# Mi calculadora javascript no me suma el ultimo valor que introduzco

Tags: javascript, html, array, arraylist, push

Gracias a otros usuarios pude hacer esta calculadora que sume bastantes numeros que ingrese, pero el problema es que al apretar "=" no me toma en cuenta el ultimo valor, me explico:

Yo aprieto **11, + , 22, +, 33, +, 44, =,**
deberia salir 110 pero me sale 66, es decir ignora el **44**

Para que me cuente el ultimo numero debo apretar "+" y despues el "=" asi:
**11, + , 22, +, 33, +, 44, +, =,** pero quiero que me sume todos los numeros al apretar igual sin tener que apretar ese ultimo signo +

Este es mi javascript

```
let cantNumeros = 0; //cantidad de numeros ingresados
let cantOperaciones = 0; //cantidad de operaciones (cuantas veces debe sumar)
let auxiliar = "";
let numeros = []; //array de todos los numeros ingresados
let operaciones = []; //array de todas las operaciones ingresadas

function init(){

    let igual = document.getElementById('igual');
    let reset = document.getElementById('reiniciar');
    let suma = document.getElementById('suma');

    let resta = document.getElementById('resta');
    let multiplicacion = document.getElementById('multiplicacion');
    let division = document.getElementById('division');
    
    let uno = document.getElementById('uno');
    let dos = document.getElementById('dos');
    let tres = document.getElementById('tres');
    let cuatro = document.getElementById('cuatro');
    let cinco = document.getElementById('cinco');
    let seis = document.getElementById('seis');
    let siete = document.getElementById('siete');
    let ocho = document.getElementById('ocho');
    let nueve = document.getElementById('nueve');
    let cero = document.getElementById('cero');


////////////////////////
    function mostrarEnPantalla( numero ) {
    pantalla.textContent = numero;
    }
    function recibeNumeros( numeroIngresado) {
    auxiliar = auxiliar + numeroIngresado;
    mostrarEnPantalla( auxiliar );
}

////////////////
    uno.onclick = function(e){
        recibeNumeros(1)
    }
    dos.onclick = function(e){
        recibeNumeros(2)
    }
    tres.onclick = function(e){
        recibeNumeros(3)
    }
    cuatro.onclick = function(e){
        recibeNumeros(4)
    }
    cinco.onclick = function(e){
        recibeNumeros(5)
    }
    seis.onclick = function(e){
        recibeNumeros(6)
    }

    siete.onclick = function(e){
        recibeNumeros(7)
    }
    ocho.onclick = function(e){
        recibeNumeros(8)
    }
    nueve.onclick = function(e){
        recibeNumeros(9)
    }
    cero.onclick = function(e){
        pantalla.textContent === '0'
        ? pantalla.textContent = "0"
        : recibeNumeros(0);
    }

    reset.onclick = function(e){
        resetear();
    }

    suma.onclick = function(e){
        recibeOperaciones("+")
        limpiar();
    }

    igual.onclick = function(e){
        recibeOperaciones("=")
    }

}

    function limpiar(){
             pantalla.textContent = "";
     }

    function resetear(){
             numeros = [];
             operaciones = [];
             cantNumeros = 0;
             cantOperaciones = 0;
             auxiliar = ""
             limpiar();
      }

    function mostrarEnPantalla( numero ) {
            pantalla.textContent = numero;
    }


//Ver que operacion he ingresado
function recibeOperaciones( operacionIngresada ) {
    if( operacionIngresada == "=" ) {
        resuelve();
    }
    else{

        operaciones.push( operacionIngresada );
        numeros.push( auxiliar );
        
        if (pantalla.textContent != "") {
            cantOperaciones++;
            cantNumeros++;
        }
        auxiliar = "";
    }
}

function resuelve() {
    let numeroA = numeros[ 0 ];
    let numeroNuevo = 0;

    for( i = 1; i < cantNumeros; i++ ) {
        numeroA = operar( numeroA, numeros[ i ], operaciones[i - 1] );
        
    }
    mostrarEnPantalla(numeroA);
    cantOperaciones = 0;
    cantNumeros = 0;
    auxiliar = "";
    
}

function operar( numeroA, numeroB, operacion ) {
    if( operacion == "+" ) {
        return parseInt(numeroA) + parseInt(numeroB);
    }
    else if( operacion == "-" ) {
        return parseInt(numeroA) - parseInt(numeroB);
    }
    else if( operacion == "/" ) {
        return parseInt(numeroA) / parseInt(numeroB);
    }
    else if( operacion == "*" ) {
        return parseInt(numeroA) * parseInt(numeroB);
    }

}

init();
```

Aca esta el css y html por si necesitan
https://github.com/JoseGodoyCebreros/Mis-codigos/tree/main/Calculadora

Comment: En resuelve, el for debería ir hasta i<= a cantNumeros, considerando que empiezas en 1, por lontanto el ultimo número no lo vas a agarrar.

Comment: Intento poner eso, pero al apretar "=" ahora me devuelve un NaN en la pantalla

Comment: tu enlace a github no funciona, bueno al menos a mí no me funciona. Intenta recuperar el último número ingresado para hacer un numeros.push(ultimonumero) justo al principio de la funcion resuelve()

Comment: @Jose Godoy Cebreros. Hola, solo agrega **numeros.push( auxiliar );** en la función **recibeOperaciones** dentro del if y antes de **resuelve()**, y debería funcionar.

Comment: Gracias, justo lo acabo de poner, me funciono

Comment: @MarcePuente jeje, me ganaste :-)

Comment: @Cris223511.dev, son raras las ocaciones en que el alumno supera al maestro (solo en velocidad), aparte jugué con ventaja...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gracias por sus sugerencias, lo resolví de esta forma:

```
function recibeOperaciones( operacionIngresada ) {

    // Poniendo el numeros.push acá
    
    numeros.push( auxiliar );
    
    if( operacionIngresada == "=" ) {
        
        resuelve();
    }
    else {

        operaciones.push( operacionIngresada );
        
        if (pantalla.textContent != "") {
            cantOperaciones++;
            cantNumeros++;
        }
        
        auxiliar = "";
     }
}
```

Y, agregando un `<=` en el `for` de Resuelve:

```
for( i = 1; i <= cantNumeros; i++ ) {
```

Comment: mucho mejor que mi sugerencia!!!

Comment: Si quieren seguir operando con el resultado final de la calculadora, en vez de push(auxiliar) hay que poner numeros.push(pantalla.textContent)

Comment: maestro, empezó preguntando y terminó dando catedra!!!.